# list files in a directory without extention in bashand save to another file

Tags: bash

I am trying to list out `filenames` in a directory that match a specific extension `.bam`, but only the `filename` without the `.bam`. I guess I could also strip off the extentions in all the files and `sort -u`, but I am not sure.  Thank you :).

**files in directory**

```
file1.bam
file1.vcf
file2.bam
file2.vcf
file3.bam
file3.vcf
```

**bash**

```
for i in *.bam; do echo "${i%.bam}"; done
file1
file2
file3
```

**desired output saved to file**

```
file1
file2
file3
```

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only part you seem to be missing is where you write the output of the `for` loop to a file.

```
for i in *.bam; do
  echo "${i%.bam}"
done > results.txt
```

Comment: I recommend that your solution pipe the output through `| sort -u` to remove duplicate file names.  Not necessary if only one extension is being looked at, but more so if wildcards in extension specs are used.